# Title case for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectsty, titlecaps

I am using ***sectsty*** and ***titlecaps*** packages to convert my section headings into title case. But, table of content remains unchanged. I want to see my table of contents also in title case.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{book} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)


% packages for setting section headings to titles caps 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\sectionfont{\titlecap}
\subsectionfont{\titlecap}
\subsubsectionfont{\titlecap}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This should be in upper case}
It is!
\subsection{a sub section}
here it is
\subsubsection{a sub sub section}
here it is

\section{This should \o be in title case}
It is!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Probably you should be looking at `titlesec` and `titletoc` to help with this.  But it is not straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `\sectionfont` and `\subsectionfont` with

```
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section#1{\oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\def\subsection#1{\oldsubsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
```

yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)


% packages for setting section headings to titles caps 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

%\sectionfont{\titlecap}
%\subsectionfont{\titlecap}
\subsubsectionfont{\titlecap}

\let\oldsection\section
\def\section#1{\oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\def\subsection#1{\oldsubsection{\titlecap{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This should be in upper case}
It is!
\subsection{a sub section}
here it is
\subsubsection{a sub sub section}
here it is

\section{This should \o be in title case}
It is!

\subsection{er\"ods-r\'enyi random graph model}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working fine except when subsection heading contains some special character such as "Er\"ods-R\'enyi Random Graph Model". any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @mqpasta: I am unable to reproduce the problem.  See updated answer which include this case.

Comment: Perhaps OP means it does not work with `øbe` in place of `\o be`?